# Trying to compile with make but missing functions like offsetof

Tags: server, 22.04, gcc, make, g++

So im trying to create an SRT server to test things out with livestreams etc and i found [srt-live-server](https://github.com/Edward-Wu/srt-live-server) and cloned that from github. I already installed SRT and compiled and make'd installed that. and downgraded to openssl 1.1.1 as srt require that.
But when download the srt-live-server and trying to make it im getting all sorts of error compileing it like

> slscore/common.hpp:120:1: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this
> declaration
> Blockquote

And

> slscore/conf.hpp:72:12: warning: ‘offsetof’ within non-standard-layout type ‘sls_conf_relay_t’ is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]

I figured it might have todo with the G++ compiler or GCC compiler. But i have no clue why and how to correct this to a lower version to get it compile. As it seems the system has a newer compiler ofcourse but the make file cant use that.

Hope anyone can help shred some light on how to correct og what i need to install the  example GCC-6/G++-6 package or where ever the g++/gcc version might be is

Node the makefile runs this line to execute: `g++ -c -g slscore/SLSMapPublisher.cpp -o obj/SLSMapPublisher.o` and then the errors arise.

Comment: I was able to build it (apparently successfully - `./bin/slc` executes and returns a usage message) on Ubuntu 22.04 with the default gcc/g++ 11.3.0 after installing the libsrt-openssl-dev package (from the universe repository). No downgrading of compilers OR openssl seems to be necessary.

Comment: Without any error outputs ? Just weird it wont let me... like im getting spammed with errors like above not small but A LOT and i simply followed srt setup with make install and dependencies they have showed on github. and then srt live server cloned and just used make - i still get build successfull so unless they are just warnings... ?